# zabbix agent is unreachable for 5 minutes

Tags: zabbix

I am getting email notification agent is unreachable for 5 minutes exactly at the same time everyday for all the agents. I didn't see any strange logs on both agent & server side. Recently we updated to 5.x and we din't chnage any configurations, still we're getting alerts at early morning only one time. There is no firewall issues. I checked the agent uptime graph in zabbix ui it's looking good there is no downtime for agent. even i increased the time out in agent still no luck. Can someone help me how to resolve it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this `housekeeper` when he working with database, if you have a lot of data, this can cause this problem.
This settings is in the server config `zabbix_server.conf` - `HousekeepingFrequency` and `MaxHousekeeperDelete`.
You can track the server log at this moment. If your server is on monitoring, look the item with name `Zabbix busy housekeeper processes, in %`.

Perhaps you have some other indicators that are increasing. You can give more information at the time of the problem (graphs/logs).

Comment: if it's housekeeper issue why we're getting only one alert at one time everyday per agent. I'm sorry i'm very new to zabbix.